# Incude error: "Cannot open source file "d3dx9.h"

Tags: directx

I've spent 2 hours trying to do this, I have DirectX SDK installed, I read 10 other questions like this and nothing worked.

- VC++ Directories are set to "$(DXSDK_DIR)Include;$(IncludePath)" and "$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86;$(LibraryPath)" for Include and Library directories respectively for all configurations—and the environment variable %DXSDK_DIR% points to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\ as expected.
- C/C++ > General settings has $(DXSDK_DIR)include listed in the Additional Include Directories.

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Got it to work by including path for all platforms (32, 64 and 86)

Comment: What version of VS are you using?  Also keep in mind that ``d3dx9`` and the legacy DirectX SDK are both deprecated. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) for some important known issues if you are going to use it with a recent version of VS. Why aren't you using DirectX 11 instead?